# Requested product doesn't exist Magento 2.1.3

Tags: magento2, products, magento2-migration-tool

I have migrated data from magento 1.7 to Magento 2.1.3.
All products working fine as well as all products are displayed in the frontend but when i will edit one product in admin than its showing me "Requested product doesn't exist" error.

Only one product has above error.

Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: I have resolved the problem by my self.

I found some products in the database without sku.
So i have assigned sku and my problem get resolved.

Comment: Hi can you tell me in which table you have update SKU in database for magento 2.

Comment: I have same issue, How can I fix? In which table I need to check?

Comment: Please check catalog_product_entity table

Answer (score 2):

The message 'Requested product doesn't exist' is triggered whenever Magento 2 tries to load a product which does not have a SKU.

To check which products do not have a SKU, sort the table catalog_product_entity by SKU. All the products with no SKU will then be grouped together. You can then fix this issue by manually adding the SKUs to the products in this table (though don't make a habit of directly editing the database - that way madness lies).

How did it happen? Poorly written extensions or product data import tools which don't use Service Contracts, or use direct SQL queries to save data into the database. Service Contracts define repositories which include checks to make sure all entity data is present and correct (including SKU) before attempting to save it. Other product import tools write data directly to the database, bypassing Magento's repositories and import/export adapters and thereby bypassing the data validation they contain too.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occured because of the extension **Solwin_Soldout**.

I disabled the extension by changing the '1' to '0' in app/etc/config.php.
After clearing the cache, the issue had been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was really stupid: I had created a new product attribute and set "integer" as its type. However, Magento 2 uses "int" for the type I was looking for. This lead to Magento 2 trying to load the "catalog_product_entity_integer" table, which does not exist. After changing the type of the new attribute from "integer" to "int", it worked!